# How do I complete the proof of proving the $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty }{ \frac { x^{ 2 }+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } } =1 } $

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { x^{ 2 }+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } } =1 } $$

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$

Then, $$ \left| \frac { x^{ 2 }+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } } -1 \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { x^{ 2 }+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } } -\frac { (x+1)^{ 2 } }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { x^{ 2 }+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } } -\frac { x^{ 2 }+2x+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { -2x }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \left| \frac { -2 }{ x^{ 3 }+2x^{ 2 }+x }  \right| <\epsilon $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac { 2 }{ \left| x^{ 3 }+2x^{ 2 }+x \right|  } <\epsilon $$

Now, we will calculate the lower bound on $x$ to force $ \left| \frac { x^{ 2 }+1 }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } } -1 \right| <\epsilon $ to hold true.

Without loss of generality, assume that $x>0$, then we get: $$\frac { 2 }{ x^{ 3 }+2x^{ 2 }+x } <\epsilon $$

$$\Longrightarrow 2<\epsilon (x^{ 3 }+2x^{ 2 }+x)$$

$$\Longrightarrow 2<\epsilon x^{ 3 }+\epsilon 2x^{ 2 }+\epsilon x$$

At this point I get stuck. How do I go from here? I can't find a way in which I could manipulate this to get it in the form $x>...$ A hint in the right direction would be beneficial.

Comment: You made an error when you moved the $x$ from the numerator to the denominator in going from $|-2x/(x+1)^2|$ to $|-2/(x^3+2x^2+x)|$.  I'd recommend starting over, and see if you still get stuck.

Comment: @BarryCipra Starting over from the point you specified?

Comment: Yes, up to there things look OK. (But Simon S's answer may save you the trouble).

Comment: You could divide numerator and denominator by $x^2$

Comment: @OttavioBartenor At which point?

Comment: Isn't immensely simpler to do it like $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}$?

Comment: @egreg Turning that into an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof isn't so straight forward. However, if we don't need such a proof that is exactly how I would do it as well.

Comment: @SimonS The point is that $\varepsilon$-$N$ proofs are *not* needed. Torture is not allowed under the Geneva convention. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Oh god yes. But I assumed from the OP that an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof required.

Comment: @SimonS It *is* easily transformed into an $\varepsilon$-$N$ proof. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Six of one; half a dozen of another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we want to find an $M$ such that $x > M \Rightarrow | \cdots | < \epsilon$.

Remember you just need to find *an* $M$; make life as easy for yourself as you can and don't care about finding a low $M$.

Hence, I would simplify and write for all $x > 0$,

$$ \left| \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2} -1 \right|  = \left| \frac { -2x }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } }  \right| \leq \frac{2x}{x^2} = \frac{2}{x}$$

Thus given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $M = 2/\epsilon$ (which is positive).

Then

$$x > M \ \Rightarrow \ x > \frac 2\epsilon \ \Rightarrow \ \frac 2x < \epsilon \ \Rightarrow \  \left| \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2} -1 \right|  < \frac 2x <\epsilon$$

---

*Added (answer to question in comments):*

We have for all positive $x$,

$$\left| \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2} -1 \right| < \frac 2x .$$

Hence given $\epsilon > 0$ if we can find an $M > 0$ such that

$$x > M \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac 2x < \epsilon$$

this implies

$$x > M \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left| \frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2} -1 \right|  < \epsilon .$$

Now, bounding $\frac 2x$ by $\epsilon$ is straight forward:

$$\frac 2x < \epsilon \quad\text{ iff }\quad  x > \frac 2\epsilon$$

Hence the choice of $M = 2/\epsilon$ does the trick.

Comment: How did you do this?: $\left| \frac { -2x }{ (x+1)^{ 2 } }  \right| \leq \frac{2x}{x^2} = \frac{2}{x}$

Comment: For all $x > 0$, $(x+1)^2 > x^2$  and thus $1/(x+1)^2 < 1/x^2$.

Comment: @nikolita For $x>0$, $(x+1)^2 > x^2$ (prove this for yourself). Therefore $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} < \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: @SimonS I am so dead set on doing it the way I was (which I admit is not a good thing), that I am kind of lost trying to figure out your explanation.

I'm especially lost when you arbitrarily chose $N = \lfloor 2/\epsilon \rfloor + 1$

Comment: I recommend trying to understand what I am doing. The basic strategy is to analyze the expression $| f(x) - L |$ and find a simple bound. Then use that simple bound so that given $\epsilon$ it is easy to find an appropriate $N$. Your working has an algebra error as pointed out by Barry and I suggest you fix that before comparing strategies.

Comment: I went back to the point that Barry said to start over from. I just don't see how I could algebraically manipulate it in order to simplify it further.

Comment: It's hard to keep track of all the manipulations that you did, but I think I have the hang of it. (Sort of).

Comment: Yes apologies for that: I changed the $N$ to $M$ because I had slightly overcomplicated it by choosing an integer value $N$ and with the change I want to emphasize the choice of $M$ we need to make is just a positive real number. The answer should now be in its final form.

Comment: Can you just run me through why you decided on $\frac { 2 }{ \epsilon } $? That always confuses me. (when an arbitrary value like that is chosen).

Comment: See addition to answer above

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}{1+\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}
=1
$$
For $x>0$, the denominator is $>1$ and it's not restrictive to assume it.

The inequality to be solved becomes then
$$
\left|-\frac{2}{x}\right|<
\varepsilon\left(1+\dfrac{2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)
$$
which is certainly satisfied if
$$
\frac{2}{x}<\varepsilon
$$
so for
$$
x>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}
$$